# Python - Write a three dimensional image from 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, itk, simpleitk

I'm trying to obtain an image from 3D array and convert it to TIF 3D. I'm using simple ITK but it doesn't work. I obtain this error message : *'in method 'WriteImage', argument 1 of type 'itk::simple::Image const &'*

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import SimpleITK as sitk

test = np.ones((20,20,20))

sitk.WriteImage(test,'test.tif')
```

-------------------- EDIT LATER ----------------------------

I try by working with "GetImageFromArray" it seems work as i keep the same size and finally i try to save but an error :

*"itk::ERROR: TIFFImageIO(0x43e8740): TIFF supports unsigned/signed char, unsigned/signed short, and float"*

Here's my code:

```
test2 = sitk.GetImageFromArray(test)
test2.GetSize()
(20, 20, 20)
sitk.WriteImage(test2, "prout.tif")
```

Comment: It does not like the input format. You sure it supports writing from an array of values and does not need you to pass the array to an image-constructor first?

Comment: This does not look like a full error message. Did you skip parts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your *sitk::Image* pixel type is not supported by the TIFF ImageIO. You need to cast to one of the pixel types listed, i.e. *sitk.UInt8*, *sitk.UInt16*, *sitk.Float32*.

You can inspect what your current pixel type is with something like:

```
print("pixel id: {0} ({2})".format(test2.GetPixelID(), test2.GetPixelIDTypeAsString())
```

Then you can convert the pixel type of your image:

```
test2 = sitk.Cast(test2, sitk.Float32)
```

or

```
test2 = sitk.Cast(test2, sitk.UInt16)
```

etc...